# Using dput for uploading package to launchpad-ppa: No host found in config

Tags: packaging, debian-based

I'm trying to upload a debian package to ppa.launchpad.net using `dput`. As mentioned in [launchpad.net help](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) I just have to use the following command:

```
dput ppa:my-lp-id/ppa <source.changes>
```

My PPA is called `main`. I built the package using `debuild -S` and try to upload the resulting `foo_0.1.2_source.changes` file using the following command:

```
dput ppa:myid/main foo_0.1.2_source.changes
```

But this results in

```
No host ppa:myid/main found in config
```

In my `dput.cf` I have the following:

```
[ppa]
fqdn                    = ppa.launchpad.net
method                  = ftp
# replace <launchpad-id> with your Launchpad ID
#incoming               = ~<launchpad-id>/ubuntu
incoming                = ~myid/ubuntu
login                   = anonymous
```

So, the host is definitely there, but what's wrong here?

**EDIT:** Seems to be a problem with dput on ArchLinux. The same command on Ubuntu worked like a charm.

Comment: Replace `ppa:myid/main` with `ppa` . `ppa` is the entry from `dput.cf` .

Answer (score 7):

I just figured this out for myself. I am on a Debian system and this is what worked for me:

The `dput` command uses the section header name from `dput.cf` as input. So, in the case you described above you would want to use the command:

```
dput ppa foo_0.1.2_source.changes
```

Here is what my `dput.cf` config looks like:

```
[stendhal-webstart]
fqdn = ppa.launchpad.net
method = ftp
incoming = ~username/stendhal-webstart/ubuntu/
login = anonymous
allow_unsigned_uploads = 0
```

So the command `dput stendhal-webstart stendhal-webstart_1.0_source.changes` worked for me. Hope this helps.

It seems that `dput` settings are a bit different on Ubuntu systems than others'.

Comment: This worked for me for the phpMyAdmin PPA
`incoming = ~phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu/`